# Data not fetching in card view while retrieving data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch database from firebase but i cant get any text in cardview. Below is the xml file of card view.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
   >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#F44336"
        android:textSize="132dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewgenere"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Genre"
        android:textSize="32sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the activity file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewUser">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
         />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is the activity file

```
  package com.example.firebasedatabase;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.firebasedatabase.Adapter.UserAdapter;
import com.example.firebasedatabase.Model.Showuser;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ViewUser extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference userdatabase;
    UserAdapter userAdapter;
    private List<Showuser>listData;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_user);


        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        listData=new ArrayList<>();

        userdatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        userdatabase.keepSynced(true);


           userdatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {


               @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    for (DataSnapshot npsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Showuser showuser=npsnapshot.getValue(Showuser.class);
                        listData.add(showuser);
                    }

                    userAdapter=new UserAdapter(listData);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {


            }
        });


    }


}
```

Below is the recycleradapter

```
package com.example.firebasedatabase.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.firebasedatabase.Model.Showuser;
import com.example.firebasedatabase.R;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;

import java.util.List;



public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    Context context;
    private List<Showuser>listData;



    public UserAdapter(Context context,List<Showuser>listData)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.listData=listData;
    }

    public UserAdapter(List<Showuser> listData) {
    }

    //
//
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
//        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.usercard,parent,false);
//        return new ViewHolder(view) {
//
//        };

        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.usercard,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        holder.txtuser.setText(new StringBuilder(listData.get(position).getShowuserName()));
        holder.txtgenre.setText(new StringBuilder(listData.get(position).getShowuserGenre()));


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView txtuser,txtgenre;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtuser=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewname);
            txtgenre=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewgenere);


        }
    }
}
```

I cannot view any text coming from firebase database.The firebase database rules are true.The view is created; just as i enter 4 data in firebase then it shows 4 card view but no text is shown and there is space between 1 card & 2 card near about 4 blank rows.

please help me out
[image: Firebase Database Image]

Comment: We're you able to get the data from firebase?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @elbertrivas- i am not getting any text but card is created as per the data

Comment: @AlexMamo i have added pls check

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`. Do you have any message in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo-Error is in the model class it shows the variable dont use.I used the different name of node in model class.Now text is coming but the card so blank rows means if one data is coming than there is gap between 1 card and 2 card. It is not in continuous one after another how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue.

```
userAdapter=new UserAdapter(listData);
recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
```

Here you are initializing your UserAdapter. Notice that you are calling the wrong constructor or perhaps you have not implemented it.

```
// You should call this instead
public UserAdapter(Context context,List<Showuser>listData)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.listData=listData;
}

// You are calling this empty constructor
public UserAdapter(List<Showuser> listData) {
}
```

You should initialize your adapter like below.

```
userAdapter=new UserAdapter(ViewUser.this, listData);
```

Comment: -showing error- Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference     holder.txtuser.setText(new StringBuilder(listData.get(position).getShowuserName()));

Comment: at com.example.firebasedatabase.Adapter.UserAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserAdapter.java:20)public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder>{

Comment: @amoljunghare can you send your **Showuser** object?

Comment: @amoljunghare try to remove your StringBuilder and just directy call for ex. holder.txtuser.setText(listData.get(position).getShowuserName());

Comment: @ elbert rivas-Error is in the Showuser it shows the variable don't use.I used the different name of node in model class.Now text is coming but the card so blank rows means if one data is coming than there is gap between 1 card and 2 card. It is not in continuous one after another how to solve this.

Comment: @amoljunghare I'm sorry I can't help you any further. However, you can always post another question.

Answer (score 0):

You miss setting the list in adapter constructor, so change below

```
public UserAdapter(List<Showuser> listData) {

}
```

With

```
public UserAdapter(List<Showuser> listData) {
    this.listData=listData;
}
```

Also, the list might be null, so change the return value of `getItemCount()`

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listData.size();
}
```

with

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listData == null? 0: listData.size();
}
```